# How to use Html.TextBoxFor with input type=time

Tags: model-view-controller, textbox

I have a model with a time value as string (09:20), I would like to display this in a TextBoxFor. Currently I have this..

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndTime, new {@class = "form-control", @title = "End time", id = "example-time-input", type = "time" })
```

with this code it display 09:25 00, I would like it to display 09.20, I dont need the seconds part. How do I accomplish that?

Comment: For a start your property should be typeof `TimeSpan`, not `string`. And `type="time"` generates the browsers HTML-5 time picker (if its supported). By default it does not display seconds unless you specify the `step` attribute so its not clear what you are doing to get the result you are claiming. For more details refer [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time)

Comment: I tried in [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DRp3BN) and `<input type="time" />` seem working properly. Can you clarify how the seconds part appears when by default it should not?